# Autorefresh or reload of the Account page

Tags: controller

I have 1 visualforce page, which opens up on clicking a button on Account Detail page. I am filling up few field  information of Account in the visualforce page and want to get those updated in Account Detail page. I am able to update those fields in Account Detail page. But, i need to refresh the browser or do F5 to refresh the page. I want to reload the Account Detail page automatically when action from VF page is done.

In the class, in Page reference, I am writing as-

```
public PageReference doRefreshAccountPage() {    
  return new PageReference('/' + this.account.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you apex class controller that you have written for you VF page, make sure that the return type of the save action button method of PageReference type.

Then you won't need an additional method to force refresh. Just simply return the reference from the save method to detail page for Account.

```
public PageReference saveCustom() {
        //you logic
        update account;
        return new PageReference('/' + this.account.Id); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi Roh77, The Save method is of Boolean type which is updating the Account record. And, I added the -  update account;, but still not refreshing the Account Detail page once back from the VF page.

Comment: Can you change the Boolean return type to PageReference and try.

Comment: There are few scenarios which happened in the code, like- mandatory field check, response from thirdparty, anyother reason of failure. This is why I have kept the return type as Boolean.So,  changing the return type to PageReference would lead to change in the overall design and implementation.

Comment: In that case you can return null whenever there is an validation error and if all goes well return the page reference to detail page. Because the method which is executing on click of the save button must return the redirected reference.

Comment: Exactly Rohit. I am also doing the same thing. I am also getting all information in debug log prior to the redirection of the VF page to the Account Detail page. However,  this below line:    return new PageReference('/' + this.account.Id); is giving me the old stale page. It seems there is some cache problem, it is not taking the fresh information from the server.

Comment: This seems to be a limitation and is available in Idea:  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code to achieve this requirement

```
    public Pagereference saveAccount() {

    if(ValidateForm()){

            try {
                update account;
                return new PageReference('/' + this.account.Id);
            }
            catch(DMLException de) {
                Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, de.getDmlMessage(0)));
                return NULL;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
                return NULL;
            }
    }else{
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, 'Validation message..'));
                return NULL;
    }
}

private Boolean ValidateForm(){
    if(string.IsBlank(account.name)){
        return false;
    }
    if(string.IsBlank(account.name)){
        return false;
    }
    if(string.IsBlank(account.name)){
        return false;
    }
    // other validations Here in same way

    return true;    
}
```

You can call save account method where I have validate the form before saving it.